# Jest testing of simple vanilla JavaScript - Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, jestjs

I'm trying to test my app using Jest and Node.js. What is the correct setup to avoid getting the following error in the terminal when running tests with JestJS?

> Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

The test for the `sum` function passes as soon as I comment out adding the event listener in the `app.js` file. I'm not even sure why is this line  as well as the `console.log('Not part...')` executed by Jest since I only export the `sum` function.

[image]

The contents of my index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>

  <button id="button">JavaScript</button>

  <script src="./app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The contents of my app.js file:

```
function sum(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}


console.log('Not part of module.exports but still appearing in terminal, why?');
var button = document.getElementById('button');
button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  console.log('button was clicked');
});


module.exports = {
  sum
};
```

The contents of my app.test.js file:

```
var { sum } = require('./app');

describe('sum', () => {
  test('adds numbers', () => {
    expect(sum(1, 2)).toBe(3);
  });
});
```

My package.json:

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest --coverage",
    "test:watch": "npm run test -- --watch"
  },
```

Comment: `getElementById` might execute too soon. Maybe put that code block in `window.load = function () {    ...     }`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`getElementById` might execute before the DOM is loaded. Put that code block in a callback that is executed when the document has been loaded. For instance:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    console.log('Not part of module.exports but still appearing in terminal, why?');
    var button = document.getElementById('button');
    button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      console.log('button was clicked');
    });
});
```